# When WepApp added to Homescreen on iPhone unable to persist Authentication Cookie

Tags: javascript, authentication, mobile-safari

I have a Web App written with Asp.Net Mvc 4. It is using Forms Authentication and I am able to have it persist a cookie so a user does not have to enter credentials in a full browser like Chrome but when I add the page to the Homescreen on my iPhone and try the same thing I am always prompted to enter my user name and password.

From what I have read I should be able to authenticate and save the response's "Set-Cookie" cookie that is returned to the local storage of the Safari Mobile Browser and on subsequent requests add the value to the request and not have to worry about entering my username and password for as long as the cookie is valid.

When I do this to submit the authentication request, I can see that the cookie is being set but I can't retrieve it's value.

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        alert("Submitting");
        $.post("Account/login", $("form").serialize(),
            function (data, textstatus, req) {
                alert(req.getAllResponseHeaders());
            });
    }
);
})
```

If I try

```
 alert(req.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"));
```

I also get nothing.
Am I even heading in the right direction? Is there a better way to do this?